# Fatal error: Call to a member function get_var() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, cron

I'm working on an application which requires me to extract a variable from a table named `wp_q33uds_campaign` using an SQL query. My application is based on WordPress, and hence I'm using WordPress' inbuilt class `wpdb` to make SQL queries for extracting information from the table as follows:

```
global $wpdb;
$d = $wpdb->get_var( 'SELECT date1 FROM wp_q33uds_campaign WHERE user_id = 337142662' );
```

Now, I'm running a cron job through my web server on the template that contains the above query, and this is the error I get in my cron error report:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function get_var() on a non-object in /home/manasge/manas.getevangelized.com/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/tuto/callback.php on line 228
```

Now, the query should return a result, ie the query doesn not return an empty result.

What seems to be wrong here?

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/23990/initialize-wordpress-environment-to-use-in-a-real-cron-script This should solve your problem

Comment: @DannyPhantom Yes, that should solve my problem. Thanks.